# Seeking maps to use on iPhone/Android app

Tags: gps, google-earth, ios, altitude

How can I get data of the earth map on the iOS sdk "Swift" containing data altitude too?

I would like to use all world map, gps position (but I think that's not a matter) and altitude of all places.

Is there an option that has less computational cost?

I've tried only Google Maps but I've read that if I will public my app release and only a few people will use it I will have to pay because it will use a lot of data.

Comment: Please ask 1 question. You can have different new questions, and what have you tried?

Comment: Would this work? PeakVisor https://peakvisor.com/en/news/3d_maps.html

Comment: Yeah something like that, but not only for peaks and mountains.